# How can I make VS Code's suggest widget auto-select the first item while not auto-expanding the suggestion details?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, editor, settings

Coding with VS Code and the `Python`, `Pylance`, `Black`, and `Jupyter` extensions, I would like to always see IntelliSense suggestions and never see documentation pop-ups unless I explicitly request them (e.g. with `Ctrl+space`). I have attempted various combinations of settings related to quick suggestions and selection mode, but every time I show the documentation once, it continues to appear every time I select a suggestion, which is very frustrating. Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Screenshot of desired behavior]

Is there a setting I'm missing that will allow me to achieve this behavior and keep it consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experimentation, the suggest widget will remember whether you toggled the suggestion details to be visible the last time you opened it. So if you want the suggestion details to be hidden the next time you open the suggest widget, then just toggle suggestion details (<kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) to be hidden and then close the suggest widget (<kbd>esc</kbd>).

To make VS Code auto-select the first suggestion item, just keep the default value of `"editor.suggestSelection": "first"` (`"first"` is the default value of the setting).

Loosely related issue ticket from the monaco-editor GitHub repo (Monaco is the editor component of VS Code): [Enable suggestion details by default #2316](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2316) (from googling "`github vscode issues suggestion details toggle default`").